# Mysql order by block several times

Tags: mysql, linux, sql-order-by

I have a query that looks like this:

> SELECT t.realtimedatas_timestamp  FROM tr_realtimedatas as t ORDER BY t.realtimedatas_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;

And my table contains these columns

> id,name,serial_number,realtimedatas_timestamp,realtimedatas_created,realtimedata_updated

when i call  `mysql --version` it give me :

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6

Everything works fine, but after i move to this new version of mysql

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

The query blocked several times to get the last data inserted in the database ordered by  `realtimedatas_timestamp`,

Is the problem with the mysql version or something else.
what is the best query to get the data ordered by a feild.

Comment: So now how are Java and Php coming into this?

Comment: i had this problem when i use java or php or using query directly

Comment: "using query directly" - that indicates Java or Php is _not_ directly involved.

Comment: thanks sir i removed java and php ,